# retrieve all tweets and retweets user ids for hashtag

Tags: python, twitter, scrapy, tweepy, scrape

how can I scraping tweets with meta data(tweet text - userid - retweets user id) based on hashtag? I'm trying to use tweepy api code :

```
import tweepy
import csv
import pandas as pd
####input your credentials here
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
#USA
# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('ua.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#usa",count=100,
                           lang="en",
                           since="2018-04-03").items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't explained what error you are seeing, however:

The legacy Twitter v1.1 standard search API (which is what `api.search` in Tweepy is calling) can only provide you data from the past 7 days. If you need Tweets since April 2018, you will need to use the premium full-archive search API.

> tweets with meta data(tweet text - userid - retweets user id)

You would need to modify your code to include the value of `tweet.user.id`. There's no Retweet count available in the legacy v1.1 Twitter API, but this value is part of the new data format in API v2.

Comment: thanks for you answer , I dont have error I want to extract tweets user id and retweets userid if there is retweets..sth like this: for tweet in tweets:
    print api.retweets(tweet.id) but I dont know how to do thar right